# What is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x+3|(\sqrt{ax+b}-2)}x$ when it exists?

Tags: calculus, limits

> For what values of $a$ and $b$ does the following limit exist and what is the limit in those cases?
>   $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x+3|(\sqrt{ax+b}-2)}x$$

Actually this is an assignment which I need to do, but I have no idea where to start, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Start by answering, "For what value of $b$ will $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt{ax+b}-2\right)=0$?"

Then, rationalize the numerator and set $b$ equal to that number to see if there are any restrictions on $a$.

Comment: clearly b should be 4

Comment: Well done!  And now simply rationalize the numerator and set $b=4$.

Comment: it should be something like this? (|x+3|(ax))/(x(sqrt(ax+4)+2)

Comment: @LamDarkkis Yes.  And are there any restrictions on $a$ as $x\to  0$ for the limit to exist?

Comment: yes, there are since the denominator have x
so I tried to cancel out the x at denominator
(x+3)(ax) at the numerator will become x(ax+3) 
therefore x can be cancelled
(ax+3)/(sqrt(ax+4)+2)

Comment: sorry for bad typesetting, I am first time to use this platform

Comment: Not quite.  For $b=4$, the limit of interest becomes $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x+3|\,a}{\sqrt{ax+4}+2}=\frac{3a}{4}$, the existence of which does not depend on $a$, although the value of the limit does depend on $a$.

Comment: Yup, I did a mistake, the numerator should be a(x+3), you are so nice, thank you so much!!^_^

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I got $-\dfrac{3a}{4}$; is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Yes.  The answer should be $3a/4$

Comment: @Dr.MV Could you explain where I went wrong?

Comment: The point $x=-3\ne +3$ is the point at which the term $|x+3|$ is zero.

Comment: @Dr.MV Ah, thank you!

Comment: @Clarinetist You're welcome!  Pleased I was able to help.

Comment: @Dr.MV Why we can set $$\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt{(ax+b)}-2)=0$$, I know it's finding the value of b, but I want to know the purpose or reason behind it. Many thanks!!

Comment: @LamDarkkis Sure.  We see that the denominator goes to zero as $x\to 0$.   Hence, for the limit of interest to exist, it is necessary that the numerator go to zero also.  Since $|x+3|\to 3$ as $x\to 0$, then we must have $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt{ax+b}-2\right)=0$.

Comment: so that means if denominator is zero and numerator not zero, we will get 'undefined', if both of them are zero, then we can do some more work to get the final answer, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  Well done.  You have it now.

Answer (score 2):

A more brute-force approach:
$$|x+3| = \begin{cases}
x + 3, & x \geq -3 \\
-(x+3) = -x - 3, & x < -3 
\end{cases}$$
so

$$\dfrac{|x+3|(\sqrt {ax+b}-2)}{x} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{(x+3)(\sqrt {ax+b}-2)}{x},  & x \geq -3 \\
\dfrac{(-x-3)(\sqrt {ax+b}-2)}{x},  & x < -3 \text{.}
\end{cases}$$
For $x$ within a "small" neighborhood of $0$, we need only worry about the $x \geq -3$ case:
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{(x+3)(\sqrt {ax+b}-2)}{x} &= (x+3)\dfrac{\sqrt {ax+b}-2}{x}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
We're not splitting the fraction since obviously $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{2}{x}$$
does not exist.

As $x \to 0$, $x + 3 \to 3$.

Being clever, we could notice that if the limit of $\dfrac{\sqrt {ax+b}-2}{x}$ exists as $x \to 0$, this can be written as
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt {ax+b}-2}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f^{\prime}(0)$$
where $f(x) = \sqrt{ax+b}$, and $f(0) = \sqrt{b} = 2$, so $b = 4$. Furthermore, $$f^{\prime}(x) = \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{ax+b}} = \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{ax+4}}\text{.}$$
We then have 
$$f^{\prime}(0) = \dfrac{a}{2\sqrt{4}} = \dfrac{a}{4}\text{.}$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{|x+3|(\sqrt {ax+b}-2)}{x} = \dfrac{3a}{4}$$
as long as $b = 4$. Any $a$ will do.

Furthermore, this relies on the existence of $$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt {ax+b}-2}{x}$$
perhaps there is a way to relax this assumption.